# Java Netbeans Can't connect to Java DB because of Error

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

please Help me, i tried the

```
grant{
     //List of granted permissions
     permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";
}
```

but it won't connect in Netbeans.
i got Windows 10 OS, and Netbeans 7.3.1 JDK 7 Update 80.. please help me

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: How are you installing the SecurityManager ?

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using external policy file ?
By default policy file would be picked from user.home/.java.policy
System wide policy file will be from java.home/lib/security/java.policy

Looks like this you are using external policy file which you have to pass to the program by using the following property.
-Djava.security.policy=mypolicy

In netbeans you have to pass this by in VM Arguments section under Run

Hope this would solve the issue.